# time going back on Android

Tags: android, time

I am developing an app, and from time to time I am getting this weird message:

```
W/SystemClock(11814): time going backwards: prev 9003590393023(ioctl) vs now 9003584533648(ioctl), tid=11856
```

what does it mean? why does it happen?

thanks!

Comment: Bad flux capacitor.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the Linux kernel? | 

https://twitter.com/twaddington/status/347427777089241088, 
http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0709.1/1138.html, 
https://plus.google.com/107810117768610116431/posts/NWYdWEvTywg

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the RTC driver of your kernel and/or the clks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what does it mean?

Presumably your device's clock was synchronized with another source (NITZ, SNTP, etc.), and it happened to be that your device was running fast.

Comment: but it happens every 15-30 minutes - is that normal?

Comment: @Himberjack: Probably not. However, it is exceedingly unlikely to have anything to do with your app, assuming that your app isn't somehow trying to alter the device's clock.

Comment: because it writes in the DDMS log that its a warning in my application (and not a system warning)

Comment: @Himberjack: You are welcome to peek at the source file that contains the log message: http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/native/libs/utils/SystemClock.cpp Beyond that, unless you can get this to occur on multiple devices, I still would not worry too much.

Answer (score 0):

Many devices will OTA update their internal clock multiple times per hour.  You can usually capture a log statement when it happens (like OTA).  My understanding it that these updates only affect what is returned by System.currentTimeMillis().  This is why it is recommended to use android's SystemClock interface for timing.

Comment: Have you a reference for that? How to be sure SystemClock has not the same problem (moreover when it's this clock that display the time jump warning).

Comment: Note for myself: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html